# Count the Number of Words that Start with each Letter in a File

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I need to take a file and print the number of times each letter of the alphabet starts a word, in a descending order of word count. For example if the file is:

```
my nice name is Mike Meller
```

then the output should be:

```
3 M
2 N
1 I
```

I need to do this in a single line. I know commands like `wc -m` and `wc -w` but I'm not sure how to iterate over each character and print it in the same way and then sort it like they want.

Answer (score 2):

One way... (edited to avoid counting the same word twice)

```
$ echo "my nice name is Mike Meller" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -f | uniq -i | sed -nr 's/^([a-z]).*/\U\1/Ip' | uniq -c | sort -r
  3 M
  2 N
  1 I
```

- `tr ' ' '\n'` change spaces into newlines
- `sort -f` sort the lines so same entries are together, even if case is different
- `uniq -i` remove duplicate words, ignoring case
- `sed -nr 's/^([a-z]).*/\U\1/Ip'` remove everything but the first letter, change all letters to upper case, and don't print the line if it doesn't start with a letter
- `uniq -c` count the lines that are the same
- `sort -r` sort descending

(replace `echo "my nice name is Mike Meller"` with `cat name-of-your-file`)

Comment: thanks but when i use this code the output is a list of words (and not of letters) and also there are numbers

Comment: @UFCInsider Hmm I just made a small correction to get rid of the numbers (I added it in my explanation originally, but forgot to edit the full line) but the rest of the word should be gone, unless you have a different `sed`... hmm

Comment: In your sed I think you need to define the group like this: `\([a-z]\)` ...edit: nope you were right. but for some reason i still see numbers in the list

Comment: @UFCInsider you added `-n` and `p`?

Comment: ok there is another problem... i need all distict words so the strategy of deleting all but the first letter of each word is not good

Comment: @UFCInsider oh so the words must be unique? You want to avoid counting the same word twice? I fixed it to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lne '
  $c{uc $_}++ for /\b\p{Alpha}/g;
  END{for (sort {$c{$b} <=> $c{$a}} keys %c) {print "$c{$_} $_"}}'
```

Note that if some letters appear in a decomposed form. For instance, if `É` is entered as `É` (that is E followed by a U+0301 combining accent) instead of the pre-composed `É` (U+00E9), then it will be counted as `E`, not `É` nor `É`.

If that's a concern, then probably the best approach is to first decompose the text (since some graphems don't have a pre-composed form) and work on a graphem cluster basis. There are some like `ﬁ` that you'd probably want to break down anyway:

Compare:

```
$ printf 'my ﬁne name is \uc9ric, maybe E\u301ric, certainly not Eric\n' |
  perl -Mopen=locale -lne '
    $c{uc $_}++ for /\b\p{Alpha}/g;
    END{for (sort {$c{$b} <=> $c{$a}} keys %c) {print "$c{$_} $_"}}'
2 E
2 N
2 M
1 C
1 FI
1 É
1 I
```

with:

```
$ printf 'my ﬁne name is \uc9ric, maybe E\u301ric, certainly not Eric\n' |
  perl -Mopen=locale -MUnicode::Normalize -lne '
    $c{uc $_}++ for NFKD($_) =~ /\b(?=\p{Alpha})\X/g;
    END{for (sort {$c{$b} <=> $c{$a}} keys %c) {print "$c{$_} $_"}}'
2 É
2 M
2 N
1 E
1 I
1 C
1 F
```

Comment: Do you know how to ignore accented words in bash/zsh? For example, `si` and `sí` (or `i` and `í` ) should be equivalent. (If you think this needs a deep explanation I could make the question)

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk:

```
gawk '
  { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) count[toupper(substr($i,1,1))]++ } 
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (key in count) print count[key], key
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a homework project, I hope? ;-)  The tricky part is that you don't want to count the "L" in Meller twice, right? Hence the "distinct".

```
$cat t
my nice name is Mike Meller
```

And then a pipeline of commands to do the transforming:

```
$tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' < t |     # Convert all to upper case
fold -b -w 1 |                # Break into one letter per line
awk -f t.awk |                # Pipe the whole mess to awk to count
sort -r -n                    # Sort in reverse numeric order
```

The awk script is best broken into a separate file, though you can just put it all into a bash one-liner:

```
$cat t.awk    
/ / {                         # Match spaces,
  for (c in wc) {dc[c]+=1}    #  Accumulate word count (wc) into doc count (dc)
  split("",wc)                #  Reset the word count
}

!/ / {                        # Match non-spaces,
  if (wc[$1] == "") wc[$1]=1  #  If haven't already seen char in this word, mark it Donny
}

# Finally, output the count and the letter
END {
  for (c in wc) {dc[c]+=1}    # Accumulate one last time, in case there is no trailing space
  for (c in dc) {print c, dc[c]}
}
```

Which produces (for me) this output:

```
$tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' < t | fold -b -w 1 | awk -f t.awk  | sort -r -n
4 M
4 E
3 I
2 N
1 Y
1 S
1 R
1 L
1 K
1 C
1 A
```

Comment: Oh wow I think I made a mistake! I meant - for each letter of the english alphabet I want a counter of how many words started with that letter!

Comment: Homework related questions seem fair game by my reckoning, so long as the asker still provides a good question. That means looking for the answer before just asking, and framing it into the simplest example of the problem possible. Homework questions can be great examples for things that are useful to know, we just don't want help vamparism and low quality questions. Looks like the asker put forward effort, so I'd say this question's fine either way. They may be a bit new to `bash`, but we all were once.